# non-ASCII commands: Is there any transcoder that uses them?

Tags: macros

In the last few months, this is the third time that I find the following kind of commands in the preable of submitted papers:

```latex
\catcode162=13 \def {\oplus}           % Option-4
\catcode163=13 \def {\relax\ifmmode\expandafter\to\else\expandafter\itemize\fi} % Option-3
\catcode164=13 \def {\subset}     % Option-6
\catcode165=13 \def {\infty}           % Option-8
\catcode166=13 \def {\mp}                % Option-7
```

and they are used in the document.

This is what I see in the editor (emacs):
[image]

It is very annoying to expand them... But the question is: Are they inserted by any kind of transcoder? I mean, anyone knows about it?

Comment: Some very nonstandard encoding.